# Remove group if contains record with status 300

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group records by ID from df and delete group if any of records has STATUS = 300.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["A0", "A0", "A0", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2"],
        "STATUS": [100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
)
```

output:

```
   ID  STATUS
0  A0     100
1  A0     100
2  A0     300
3  A1     100
4  A1     100
5  A1     100
6  A2     300
7  A2     100
8  A2     100
```

I would like to get:

```
   ID  STATUS
0  A1     100
1  A1     100
2  A1     100
```

I tried:
dfnew = df1.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['STATUS'] != 300)

But I got the error:
TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
df1.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: 300 not in x['STATUS'].to_list())
```

Comment: If I want delete groups with STATUS 300 + 500 can I use? .filter(lambda x: [300, 500] not in x['STATUS'].to_list())

Comment: You could do `df1.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: not all(i in x['STATUS'].to_list() for i in (300, 500)))`. Replace all with `any` in case you want to filter on either of them

Comment: `any` is cheaper than `all`. @mozway answer is by far better than ours ;)

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel it's more efficient if the aim is to filter groups that contain either `300` or `500`, but I'm not sure if that is what OP wants

Comment: Another option, without resorting to list conversion: ``df1.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x.STATUS.ne(300).all())`` or ``df1.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: ~x.STATUS.eq(300).any())``. If the OP is interested in speed, then avoiding lambda, and taking a longer approach with `transform` is likely a better choice

Answer (score 4):

An efficient method to match any value from a list (see OP's comment) is to use `isin` coupled with `groupby`+`transform`:

```py
df1[~df1['STATUS'].isin([300, 500]).groupby(df1['ID']).transform('any')]
```

output:

```
   ID  STATUS
3  A1     100
4  A1     100
5  A1     100
```

Comment: This works if the groups to be filtered contain either `300` or `500`, not if the condition is that they should contain both.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it is with `transform`. We create a mask of group IDs where their max is not 300. We could also use `not in` or whatever logic we decide

```py
df1[df1.groupby('ID')['STATUS'].transform(lambda d: d.max() != 300)]

# or this for 300 + 500

df1[df1.groupby('ID')['STATUS'].transform(lambda d: d.max() not in (300, 500))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`df1[df1.STATUS != 300]`

Comment: It will not work, I want to delete all records with the same ID (group) if any records has STATUS= 300.

Comment: Your solution will delete only records with status 300, but another records with the same ID and another ID will stay.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[~df1.ID.isin(df1.query("STATUS==300").ID)]


  ID  STATUS
3  A1     100
4  A1     100
5  A1     100
```